# Blockchain.info websocket not working

Tags: blockchain, websockets

I have been trying to get this code to work and I get a blank page no response at all from the server what is wrong with the code? or has blockchain.info changed something in their code? Can some help???

Here is the code i'm using : http://btcthreads.com/websocket.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hosting a [webvisualization](https://blocks.wizb.it/) that depends on the websocket API from blockchain.info. The API stopped working at exactly 16:40:45 GMT yesterday (march 1st) for me.

This API has gone down in the past, let's hope it goes up fast.

EDIT: for me it is working again (since 13:50:14 GMT).

Comment: Its an awesome site you got there mike! which of the non permission based api's is the best to use?

Comment: All blockchain explorers (and a bunch of other bitcoin companies) have APIs nowadays, however most are aimed towards people wanting to know specific transactions, while for my globe I wanted all transactions (+relay IP address). For this reason I choose blockchain.info at the time. Disadvantage is that it does go down a lot..

Comment: I need to verify if transactions have been confirmed by at least 3 nodes. I have the addresses in a database and I was going to run a cron job every 15 min hitting https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/14hYpVjonymPS1jwSuFsfE188f3FJtL7NE?confirmations=3 to see if there is a balance or not on that address. How reliable is that API does it go down often?

Comment: "been confirmed by at least 3 nodes" I think you mean 3 confirmations, there is a big difference. ---- in my experience it goes down ~once a month, but most of the time just for an hour or two.